# The request timed out before the page could be retrieved. asp.net web application long server processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

i have a web application which which proccesses some request on some data that client selects, when the client selects more than 20 objects and clicks on proceed the client recieves this error, because the server takes a long time to process, however if the records are less and hence a timely response is recieved, no such error comes can someone help me on this?

i have increased the sessiontimeout as well as set the

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the `executionTimeout` in your web.config...this only applies if debug is set to false however.

```
<httpRuntime 
    executionTimeout="some number"
  />
```

If this alone does not solve your issue, check out this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/02/20/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net.aspx) which goes into a bit more depth on how to structure your timeouts. Note the IIS reference towards the bottom...

Comment: have set this to this value <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600000" its still not working

Comment: Updated post...check above...also your debug is set to false?

Comment: do you mean this ? <compilation debug="true">

Comment: i have set the compilation debug attribute to false it dint work :(

Comment: @Jamil The only other item I could suggest is checking out the linked blog post on a more in depth walk through to see if it cures the problem